# Paperclip putting the date and some strange stuff on the end of file names? (This is not the fingerprint.)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, image, amazon-s3, paperclip

I am duplicating a file and sending it somewhere else with the following code:

```
thing.image = other_thing.image
```

However when the new file is getting put somewhere it has the following strange date and stuff on the end:

Original file:

```
test-picture.png
```

New strange file:

```
test-picture20111116-15550-23tmub.png
```

However the new record is getting saved with the original file names, so the duplicate file does now match the duplicate file name record in the database.

Does anyone know why this would be happening?

Note: This is all stored in an S3 bucket.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed this encase anyone else is having the same problem, it turns out if you don't do a direct assignment but do it like this it works:

```
tmp_thing = thing.image

other_thing.image = tmp_thing
```